# Indefinite Integration with trigonometric functions

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals

How to integrate
$$\frac{\sec^2 x}{({\sec x+\tan x})^{9/2}}$$
with respect to $x$.
I tried to express the denominator in the form of half angles but i could not succeed

Comment: Always try to write your question in Latex. Is this what you meant?

Comment: Yes that's what I really meant. :)

Answer (score 6):

Big Hint:

Use the substitution $u=\sec x+\tan x$, and notice that $\frac{1+u^2}{2u}=\sec x$.